# Parameter as pointer not being correctly incremented

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, pointers, parameter-passing

I have a function which counts the number of vowels and consonants in a string:

```
void CountVowelsConsonants(char* str, int *vowels, int *consonants){
    size_t size=strlen(str);
    //size-1 because of the '\n' at the end of the string when pressing enter
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; ++i) {
        char c = str[i];
            if(c=='A' || c== 'E' || c=='I' || c== 'O' || c=='U' ||
                    c=='a' || c== 'e' || c=='i' || c== 'o' || c=='u'){
                *vowels++;
            }
        }
    *consonants= size-1 - *vowels;
    }
```

But when I call this function, like this for example:

```
int vowels;
int consonants;
CountVowelsConsonants("abc", &vowels, &consonants);
```

it returns:

```
Vowels: -858993460
Consonants: 858993463
```

instead of:

```
Vowels: 1
Consonants: 2
```

I would like to know why this is the case.

I have a factorial function which has a similar implementation of the pointer and it works correctly:

```
void factorial(int n, int*fac){
    *fac=1;
    for (int i = 2; i <=  n; ++i) {
        *fac*=i;
    }
}
```

Acessing the fact pointer in the factorial function will alter the value correctly. The only difference is that in the `CountVowelsConsonants` function I'm incrementing by 1 instead of multiplying.

However, if I access the vowels pointer in the CountVowelsConsonants function to increment it will produce errors in the counting.

My IDE (CLion) will grey out the `*` in `*vowels`, indicating that the pointer operator in
`*vowels++;` is useless.

Any ideas as to why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters if the variables `vowels` and `consonants` are declared in main (or other function) then they are not initialized and has indeterminate values. You need to write

```
int vowels = 0;
int consonants = 0;
CountVowelsConsonants("abc", &vowels, &consonants);
```

The first function parameter should be declared with the qualifier const because the passed string is not changed in the function.

```
void CountVowelsConsonants( const char* str, int *vowels, int *consonants);
```

By the way the second and third parameters shall have the type `size_t`.

```
void CountVowelsConsonants( const char* str, size_t *vowels, size_t *consonants);
```

Within the function the call of `strlen` for the passed string is inefficient.

```
size_t size=strlen(str);
```

The variable `i` within the loop shall be declared with the type `size_t`.

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < size ; ++i) {
```

But without calling the function `strlen` the loop could look simpler

```
for ( ; *str != '\0'; ++str ) {
    char c = *str;
    if(c=='A' || c== 'E' || c=='I' || c== 'O' || c=='U' ||
            c=='a' || c== 'e' || c=='i' || c== 'o' || c=='u'){
        ++*vowels;
    }
    else {
       ++*consonants;
    }
 }
```

This expression

```
*vowels++;
```

is incorrect. It is equivalent to the expression

```
*( vowels++ );
```

that is the pointer itself is incremented.

You should write

```
++*vowels;
```

This expression

```
*consonants= size-1 - *vowels;
```

is also incorrect.

If you are using the variable `size` obtained by a call of `strlen` then you have to write

```
*consonants= size -*vowels;
```

Pay attention to that the function will work incorrectly if the passed string contains spaces or a punctuation symbol.

So it would be more correct to declare the loop within the function at least the following way

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

for ( ; *str != '\0'; ++str ) {
    char c = *str;

    if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )c ) ) {
        if(c=='A' || c== 'E' || c=='I' || c== 'O' || c=='U' ||
                c=='a' || c== 'e' || c=='i' || c== 'o' || c=='u'){
            ++*vowels;
        }
        else {
           ++*consonants;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your answer is super complete. I learned a lot from it. I have two questions if you don't mind: why size_t instead of int (I assume it's because they're positive values?) and why is the call to strlen inefficient in this case?

Comment: @Skatinima The function strlen have the return type size_t. An object of the type int can be not large enough to contain any value of an object of the type size_t. Calling strlen you are traversing the string the first time. Then in the for loop you are traversing the same string the second time.

Comment: @Skatinima Pay attention to that in main vowels and consonants also shall have the type size_t and if you are using the function printf to output them you have to use the conversion specifier %zu.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
*vowels++;
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
*vowels;            // this does nothing, that's what your IDE was telling you
vowel = vowels + 1; // this increments the vowels pointer,
                    // which is also pretty useless here
```

you need to write this:

```
(*vowels)++;
```

which is equivalent to this and which is what you actually want:

```
*vowels = *vowels + 1;
```

The [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of the `++` operator is 1, whereas the precedence of the `*` (dereference) operator is 2.